# Keyboard shortcut for selecting text editor in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

I find myself having to reach for my mouse a lot to re-select my code after running it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ctrl+tab

This brings up all current tabs, but just tapping it will bring you to your most recent tab and cursor position.